# Adding products to shopping cart results in error

Tags: php, mysqli

My issue is that when I try to access my cart after adding products to it I keep getting the same error,

> "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
>   given"

with this line of code:

> $itemnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($itemsresult);

```
<?php
function showcart()
{
    require('connect.php');
    if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'])) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'])) {
            $custquery = "SELECT id, status from orders WHERE customer_id = " . $_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] . " AND status < 2;";
            $custresult = mysqli_query($con, $custquery);
            $custrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($custresult);
            $itemsquery = "SELECT products.*, orderitems.*, orderitems.id AS itemid FROM products, orderitems WHERE orderitems.product_id =products.id AND order_id = " . $custrow['id'];
            $itemsresult = mysqli_query($con, $itemsquery);
            $itemnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($itemsresult);
        } else {
            $custquery = "SELECT id, status from orders WHERE session = '" . session_id() . "' AND status < 2;";
            $custresult = mysqli_query($con, $custquery);
            $custrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($custresult);
            $itemsquery = "SELECT products.*, orderitems.*, orderitems.id AS itemid FROM products, orderitems WHERE orderitems.product_id = products.id AND order_id = " . $custrow['id'];
            $itemsresult = mysqli_query($con, $itemsquery);
            $itemnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($itemsresult);
        }
    } else {
        $itemnumrows = 0;
    }
    if ($itemnumrows == 0) {
        echo "You have not added anything to your shopping cart yet.";
    } else {
        echo "<table cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>Item</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>Unit Price</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>Total Price</strong></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while ($itemsrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsresult)) {
            $quantitytotal = $itemsrow['price'] * $itemsrow['quantity'];
            echo "<tr>";
            if (empty($itemsrow['image'])) {
                echo "<td><img src='productimages/dummy.jpg' width='50' alt='" . $itemsrow['name'] . "'></td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td><img src='productimages/" . $itemsrow['image'] . "' width='50' alt='" . $itemsrow['name'] . "'></td>";
            }
            echo "<td>" . $itemsrow['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $itemsrow['quantity'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><strong>&pound;" . sprintf('%.2f', $itemsrow['price']) . "</strong></td>";
            echo "<td><strong>&pound;" . sprintf('%.2f', $quantitytotal) . "</strong></td>";
            echo "<td>[<a href='delete.php?id=" . $itemsrow['itemid'] . "'>X</a>]</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            @$total = $total + $quantitytotal;
            $totalquery = "UPDATE orders SET total = " . $total . " WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'];
            $totalresult = mysqli_query($con, $totalquery);
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td>TOTAL</td>";
        echo "<td><strong>&pound;" . sprintf('%.2f', $total) . "</strong></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<p><a href='checkout.php'>Go to the checkout</a></p>";
    }
}

?>
```

Heres my showcart page, also getting the same error with this line:

> $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

```
<?php
session_start();
require("header.php");
require("functions.php");
echo "<h1>Your shopping cart</h1>";
showcart();
if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM']) == TRUE) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM orderitems WHERE order_id = " . $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] . ";";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($numrows >= 1) {
        echo "<h2><a href='checkout.php'>Go to the checkout</a></h2>";
    }
}
require("footer.php");
?>
```

My header page as well, when I click the viewcart link it outputs same errors as above blocks of code..

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_CHANGEID']) == TRUE) {
    session_unset();
    session_regenerate_id();
}
include("connect.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
    <h1 style="color:#ffffff"> <?php echo $site; ?> </h1>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="<?php echo $access; ?>">Home</a>
    <a href="showcart.php">View Basket/Checkout</a></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="bar">
        <?php
        include("bar.php");
        echo "<hr />";
        if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE) {
            echo "Logged in as <strong>'" . $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] . "'</strong>[<a href='" . $access . "logout.php'>logout</a>]";
        } else {
            echo "<a href='" . $access . "login.php'>Login</a>";
        } ?></div>
    <div id="main">
```

Comment: replace $custrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($custresult); with $custrow = mysqli_fetch_row($custresult);

Comment: didnt fix the issue @PRANAV

Comment: you need to test whether after executing query does it get records try this for each query debug it using echo "<pre>"; print_r($yourVariable);

Comment: @PRANAV it goes to database table, when I select product it goes to table but gives error as i said and doesnt go to cart page to complete purchase

Comment: your code need to debugged only and using above detail i am not able to do the same and i can guide only...but am not able to get what actually going wrong with your code..Sorry Bro..!

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($custrow)` and `;` is not required at end of select statement

Comment: @Undefined_variable object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: try `echo $itemsquery`

Comment: @Undefined_variable the echo didnt output anything. Still at a loss at what the problem is, it still just prints "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given " to the screen and doesnt update the cart on site but adds an order to the table.